# apache-airflow-providers-google in MWAA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, mwaa

I tried to install apache-airflow-providers-google in MWAA but it seems that Airflow does not pick the library:

```
    Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/mi-framework/jobs/google_analytics/main.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/mi-framework/jobs/google_analytics/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.google import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.google'
```

I have the following requirements.txt file:

```
apache-airflow[postgres]==2.0.2
apache-airflow[mysql]==2.0.2
apache-airflow-providers-google==6.0.0
sqlalchemy==1.3.24
google-api-python-client==2.27.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
sentry-sdk
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show output of pip freeze?

Comment: How can I see that @Elad?

Comment: you can run pip freeze

Comment: yes but where @Elad, MWAA is runnig in managed environment

Comment: Hi @Bolde, I'm still having the issue with MWAA 2.2. Do you do other additional settings?

Comment: No and it won’t work- I texted with the AWS support and there is a collision between the libraries. I recommend that you extract the logic for what you are trying to do in a microservice and habe airflow just orchestrating it. @nolw38

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your airflow version of MWAA is 2.0.*

So, based on the following link from airflow documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/index.html You need to downgrade your apache-airflow-providers-google to 3.0.0

[Image from airflow documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cl8W.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30896920)

Answer (score 1):

The resolution was, upgrading MWAA to 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using below requirements made:

- MWAA work with Bigquery operators
- Allowed me to add a google cloud connection from the Airflow UI

Make sure to have the same versions! (I am using MWAA 2.2.2)

```
apache-airflow[postgres]==2.2.2
apache-airflow[mysql]==2.2.2
apache-airflow-providers-google==6.0.0
sqlalchemy==1.3.24
google-api-python-client==1.12.8
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
```

Hope it can help!